# Pull array object values then push to another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

Hi! I am trying to loop through an object to execute a function that will read each value inside every grouped array but I keep on having only the first group.

I was trying to iterate and add push it on an array but I wasn't able to pull off the expected result.

Here's the expected result, but only the first grouped array is being returned.

```js
console.log ->
{
  "order_details": [
    {
      "order_seq": "2104150001"
    },
    {
      "order_seq": "2105110005"
    },
    {
      "order_seq": "2106220007"
    },
    {
      "order_seq": "2105260007"
    }
  ]
}

console.log ->
{
  "order_details": [
    {
      "order_seq": "2105270001"
    }
  ]
}

console.log ->
{
  "order_details": [
    {
      "order_seq": "2104090006"
    },
    {
      "order_seq": "2105060001"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my script snippet:

```js
var objectPayload = {
  "0": [{
    "order_seq": "2104150001"
  }, {
    "order_seq": "2105110005"
  }, {
    "order_seq": "2106220007"
  }, {
    "order_seq": "2105260007"
  }],
  "1": [{
    "order_seq": "2105270001"
  }],
  "2": [{
    "order_seq": "2104090006"
  }, {
    "order_seq": "2105060001"
  }]
};

var result = Object.keys(objectPayload).map((key) => objectPayload[key]);

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  var testList = {
    "order_details": []
  };
  setTimeout(function() {
    let jsonSeqNo;
    result[i].map(function(value) {
      jsonSeqNo = {
        'order_seq': value.order_seq
      };
    });
    testList.order_details.push(jsonSeqNo);
    console.log(testList);
  }, i * 500);
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't run, and your code isn't in a snippet

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour]

Comment: `.map` (inside the setTimeout) without returning a value will return `value` - you probably wanted `...map(function(value) { return result[i].map(function (value) { 'order_seq': value.order_seq })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as easy as:

```js
var objectPayload = {
  "0": [{
    "order_seq": "2104150001"
  }, {
    "order_seq": "2105110005"
  }, {
    "order_seq": "2106220007"
  }, {
    "order_seq": "2105260007"
  }],
  "1": [{
    "order_seq": "2105270001"
  }],
  "2": [{
    "order_seq": "2104090006"
  }, {
    "order_seq": "2105060001"
  }]
};

const result = Object.values(objectPayload).map((group) => ({
  order_details: group
}));

result.forEach(entry => console.log(entry));
```

---

With `Object.values` you will get array of groups. Then using `Array.prototype.flat` you can flatten the array.

Comment: hi! thank you for your time. I kind of edited my original post to show the expected result I was trying to pull off.. thanks! :)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not fully clear what you want to achieve. Do you just want to console log? Or you want to create an array of `{ order_details: [] }`?

Comment: Updated the code, probably it's something you wanted to achieve. If not, please provide more precise explanation.